# Cual es la mejor manera para guardar en un servidor datos geográficos?

Tags: base-de-datos, geolocalización, storage, almacenamiento, geolocation-api

estoy haciendo una API REST la cual debe guardar en el servidor un objeto recibido por un método post con datos geográficos (una ruta con puntos de lat i long).Puesto que la estructura de datos recibida(Json) puede llegar a ser considerablemente grande, qual seria la mejor forma de guardar estos datos en el servidor? En un capo de la misma base datos o generando un archivo (gpx por ejemplo)? La intención será consultar estos datos a menudo por los usuarios.

Comment: Esto esta totalmente basada en opiniones.. y cual seria el problema de guardarlo en una base de datos?

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].